# Ember selectize - remove value from non-multiple

Tags: ember.js, selectize.js

I am working on an Ember application - and there is a selectize input.
http://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-selectize/

The template input looks like this

```
  {{
    forms/form-input
    type="selectize"
    label="Campaign Reference"
    name="campaignReference2"
    error=errors.campaignReference
    optionValuePath="id"
    optionLabelPath="name"
    placeholder=selectizeText
    content=myOptions
    createItem= (action createItem)
    removeItem=(action removeItem)
    removeValue=(action removeValue)
    filter=true
    multiple=false
  }}
```

and in my form extender - I have the following functions

```
  myOptions: ['Rick', 'Maggie', 'Glen'],
  selectizeText: 'Please type your text here',

  createItem(item) {
    this.set('myOptions', [item]);
  },

  removeItem(item) {
    console.log('Remove item', item);
  },

  removeValue(item) {
    console.log('Remove value', item);
  },

  selectItem(item) {
    console.log('Select item', item);
  }
```

--
when I use the selector - I can create a new item -- and the createItem function is fired correctly.

But when I delete -clear the select -- neither the remoteItem or removeValue functions are invoked.

---

there is a handler in place that eventually goes to this component. I am unsure why this input has no name property appended to it -- and I don't see it getting added when the form is submitted.

```
  <div class="{{name}}">
    {{ember-selectize
      content=localisedOptions
      optionValuePath=(or optionValuePath "content.id")
      optionLabelPath=(or optionLabelPath "content.name")
      value=value
      placeholder=placeholder
      filter=filter
      select-item=(action (or selectItem defaultSelectItem))
      optionFunction=(or optionFunction null)
      itemFunction=(or itemFunction null)
      create-item=(or createItem null)
      remove-item=(or removeItem null)
      remove-value=(or removeValue null)
      disabled=disabled
      multiple=multiple
    }}
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi again. Would it be possible for you to create a reproduction in Ember Twiddle? You can add an addon by adding its name and version to the addons hash in the twiddle.json file.

Comment: @Gaurav - I did come across such a twiddle -- it was missing params -- for a non-multiple it invokes the actions -- select-value, select-item --- for multiple - it hits remove-item, remove-value

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/9f3883fc1155a7bc9cb43c212643843d?openFiles=templates.my-route.hbs%2C&route=%2Fmy-route